# state.getState() is not a function while updating to redux 4

Tags: jquery, redux, angular6, rxjs6, redux-observable

Currently i am working on migration from angular 5 to 6. While updating to redux 4 i am getting error as store.getState() is not a funtion

```
export interface IAppState {
    source1: IEmployee[],
    source2: IEmployee[],
}    
export type FSAction = FluxStandardAction<any, MetaData | null | number>;
```

this is the code for epic middleware.
Here i am facing issue as **store.getState()** is not a function while updating to redux 4

```
employeeValues_Epic: Epic<FSAction, IAppState> = (action$, store) => action$
.ofType(APP_Actions.ActionTypes.APP_EMPLOYEE_VALUES).pipe(
  switchMap(data => {  
       let state1: IEmployee[] = [];
       try {
            console.log("in All domain  iteration");
            state1 = store.getState().source1.state;        
       } catch (error) {
           console.error(error);
    }
    return observableFrom(state1);
  }));`
```

Currently i am working on migration from angular 5 to 6. While updating to redux 4 i am getting error as store.getState() is not a funtion

Comment: You have the [jquery] and [angular6] tags here, how are those applicable? What version of redux-observable are you using?

Comment: redux: 4.0.0 and redux-observable: 1.0.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the migration doc https://redux-observable.js.org/MIGRATION.html#accessing-state

Presuming redux-observable v1 and rxjs v6.

- Instead of `store$.getState()` it have updated to `store$.value`.
- Replace `Observablefrom` to `from`. (rxjs 5 to 6)
- `ofType` should be in the pipe.

```
const employeeValues_Epic: Epic<FSAction, IAppState> = (action$, store$) => action$
.pipe(
  ofType(APP_Actions.ActionTypes.APP_EMPLOYEE_VALUES),
  switchMap(data => {  
       let state1: IEmployee[] = [];
       try {
            console.log("in All domain  iteration");
            state1 = store$.value.source1.state;        
       } catch (error) {
           console.error(error);
       }
       return from(state1);
  }));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here after updating to redux 4 and rxjs 6 syntax has been changed as below and getState() function has been changed to value property.

```
`employeeValues_Epic: Epic<FSAction, FSAction, IAppState, any> = (action$, store) => action$
.ofType(APP_Actions.ActionTypes.APP_EMPLOYEE_VALUES).pipe(
  switchMap(data => {  
       let state1: IEmployee[] = [];
       try {
            console.log("in All domain  iteration");
            state1 = store.value.source1.state;        
       } catch (error) {
           console.error(error);
    }
    return observableFrom(state1);
  }));`
```